# Need a mock http server that allows uploading of files for iOS unit tests

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, http, mocking

I need a to use a mock service to create unit tests for my network requests in the app.
Part of my network request requires uploading a file.
Would appreciate help finding an Objective-c http mock server that can support this.

Thanks!

Comment: Check if this supports that feature - https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer